# MySQL, SELECT column value when using GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql

I want to SELECT the `asset_id`, `category_name`, *and* `Fixture ID` for assets with 2 or less properties (2 or less rows in `asset_property` table). So far all I have is the `asset_id` and `category_name`. The `Fixture ID` may not exist for all assets. If it does, it would be the `property_value` from a row with `property_id 1`

### EXAMPLE OF DESIRED RESULTS

**asset_property** table:

```
| asset_id | property_id | property_value |
|:--------:|:-----------:|:---------------|
| 100      | 1           | A-6            |*
| 100      | 6           | Blue           |
| 104      | 1           | CC-7           |*
| 104      | 6           | Blue           |
| 104      | 4           | 12"            |
| 105      | 1           | B-1            |*
| 108      | 1           | HR-1           |*
| 109      | 3           | 500            |
| 109      | 4           | 1"             |
```

*`property_id` 1 is the `Fixture ID`

Desired results:

```
| asset_id | category_name | property_value*|
|:--------:|:-------------:|:---------------|
| 100      | Flooring      | A-6            |
| 104      | Flooring      | CC-7           |
| 105      | Kitchen Equip | B-1            |
| 108      | Plumbing      | HR-1           |
| 109      | Plumbing      |                |
```

*`property_value` is the `Fixture ID` if the `property_id` is `1`

### MY MYSQL SO FAR

MySQL:

```
SELECT asset_property.asset_id, category_name
FROM asset_property
LEFT JOIN asset
ON asset.asset_id = asset_property.asset_id
LEFT JOIN category
ON category.category_id = asset.category_id
GROUP BY asset_property.asset_id
HAVING COUNT(asset_property.asset_id) <= 2
```

[image: mysql explained]

Results from MySQL:

```
| asset_property.asset_id | category_name |
|:-----------------------:|:--------------|
| 3048                    | Parking Lot   |
| 3519                    | Kitchen       |
| 3522                    | Kitchen       |
| 3597                    | Flooring      |
(etc...)
```

So I need to also `SELECT` the `property_value WHERE` the `property_id = 1`. I hope this makes sense, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe switch/case would be appropriate for this query

```
SELECT asset_property.asset_id, category_name,
( CASE property_id 
       WHEN 1 THEN property_value
       ELSE 0
  END
)
FROM asset_property
LEFT JOIN asset
     ON asset.asset_id = asset_property.asset_id
LEFT JOIN category
     ON category.category_id = asset.category_id
GROUP BY asset_property.asset_id
HAVING COUNT(asset_property.asset_id) <= 2
```

Hope that helps..